# Is it possible to load an external page?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html

How can I load an external page (ex: http://www.google.pt) to a div in my page?

I've tried html5 like this:

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "<iframe src='http://www.google.com' height='100%' width='100%'></iframe>";
```

but it doesn't load.

When I put a page from my domain, it properly loads.

---

How can I load an external page (from another domain) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some cross-domain restrictions because of which you cannot load any external site directly into an iframe on your page.

However you can try the following jQuery plugin for making cross-domain AJAX requests;

https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/blob/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js

Answer (score 1):

Google does not let itself be loaded from within an iframe.

Comment: Is it possible to load into another thing (put on a div or something like that).

Comment: No, the Same Origin Policy prevents this.

Answer (score 1):

Loading this iframe gives this error : `Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.`

Which means that Google doesn't allow you to do this. If you want to use Google Search on your site, you can use [Google Custom Search](http://www.google.com/cse/).

Answer (score 0):

You should really do this server-side, because including a page on the client-side can have bad effects. For a start, Google won't read a page loaded with an iframe.

It's a pretty cheap way to do things, does your server not support PHP?